# Laplace approximation for small number of data

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, inference, central-limit-theorem, laplace-approximation

When a large number of data points is available, according to the central limit theorem, Laplace method can give an efficient, good approximation of posterior as a Gaussian distribution centered at its mode. However, in small data regime this approximation is expected to be worse. What's the best way to efficiently approximate a posterior multivariate distribution (with intractable normalization constant) when only a small number of data is available? Is there anything recommended in such cases beyond numerical computation of posterior according to Bayes theorem (which can be quite inefficient programmatically)?